# How can one write a templated function that takes a generic iterator as a parameter

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, c++98

I've been writing a templated static class. For one of the methods, I want to be able to pass in any iterator not just one from a specific data structure like List.

```
template <class T> 
class Foo
{
public:
      template<typename InputIterator>
      static bool bar(T&, InputIterator start, InputIterator end);
};

template <class T, typename InputIterator>
bool Foo<T>::bar(T& data, InputIterator start, InputIterator end)
{
    typename InputIterator::const_iterator it = start;
    while(it != end)
    {
        //logic here
        it++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Above is an example of what I've tried but I keep getting various compiler errors for different variations of this basic design.

Comment: What compiler errors? Add that to the question.

Comment: What is `&T`? It should be `T&`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have my source code in front of me when I asked this question (work issue and I asked from home), so a few there were a few issues with my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to define a nested member function template is:

```
template <class T>
template <typename InputIterator>
bool Foo<T>::inRange(T&, InputIterator start, InputIterator end)
{
    typename InputIterator::const_iterator it = start;
    while(it != end)
    {
        //logic here
        it++;
    }
    return true;
}
```